# Deleting a document from a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called customers and it contains documents.
I have written a function to delete a document using the field and its value which takes as arguments.
But it doesn't remove any customer as expected. Can anybody show me where I have gone wrong?

```
function (fieldName, value) {
  db.customers.remove({x : y});
}
```

I called the function from the mongo terminal as below.

```
db.loadServerScripts();
removeDocument("firstName", "Sam");
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a typo while inserting your code, or `db.customers.remove({x: y});` should be `db.customers.remove({fieldName: value});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your function so that the arguments become part of the query object. You can do this using either computed property or bracket notation.

**Using computed property:**

```
function removeDocument(fieldName, value) {
    db.customers.remove({[fieldName]: value});
}
```

**Using bracket notation**

```
function removeDocument(fieldName, value) {
    var query = {};
    query[fieldName] = value;
    db.customers.remove(query);
}
```

Comment: This is excellent explanation. Can you please tell me which would be the better approach out of above two ways ?

Comment: That depends on your whether your MongoDB version supports computed properties (MongoDB 3.2 and above supports ES6), no better approach as they do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

db.collection.remove is deprecated so use deleteOne or deleteMany(For deleting multiple documents)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).